# How to grep only the first string in a line

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I'm writing a script that checks a list of all the users connected to the server (using who) and writes to the file Information the list of usernames of only those having letters a, b, c or d. This is what I have so far:

```
 who | grep '[a-d]' >> Information
```

However, the command who displays this:

```
username pts/148      2019-01-29 16:09 (IP address)
```

What I don't understand is why my grep search is also displaying the pts/148, date, time, and IP address. I just want it to send the username to the file Information.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `grep` shows matching lines. This line matches.

Comment: Where did you tell it to only output part of the line, instead of the full line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way is to use the [command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) `cut` to get the first part of the string only.

```
who | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | grep '[a-d]' >> Information
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk to output records where the first clumn matches `[a-d]`:

```
$ who | awk '$1~/[a-d]/' >> Information
```

Using `grep` to search for lines with `[a-d]` before the first space:

```
$ who | grep -o "^[^ ]*[a-d][^ ]*" >> Information
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the first word, otherwise `grep` will display the entire line that has the matching text. You could use `awk`:

```
who | awk '{ if (substr($1,1,1) ~ /^[a-d]/ ) print $1 }' >>Information
```